# JS, a way to have a button refresh the result and print it on the page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
      function makeid() {
        var text = "";
        var char_list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
          text += char_list.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * char_list.length));
        }
        return text;
      }
      console.log(makeid(8));
      makeid(8);
      document.write(makeid());
    </script>
```

Hey, guys. I have this code currently in my HTML, I'm wondering how I can have the output of this code printed on the page and then refreshed everytime I click an HTML button. If you have any questions I'll try to answer them best I can.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events1  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    <div id="content"></div>
    <button id="myBtn"></button>
    <script>
        var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        btn.onclick = function(){
            function makeid(l) {
                var text = "";
                var char_list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
                for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    text += char_list.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * char_list.length));
                }
                return text;
            }
            console.log(makeid(8));
            var id = makeid(8);
            content.innerHTML = id;
        }
    </script>
```

Everytime the button is clicked, your function will be triggered and the generated Id will be put inside the `<div id="content"></div>`

[Here is the codepen for testing](https://codepen.io/jeremiahc/pen/MQqayr)